# PHP: Select a value from an imploded array in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, tags

I have a tag system where the tags are stored inside a row as an imploded array like so: 
"value1, value2, value3, etc..."
And I'm trying to make a tag search page but I have no idea how to convert it to an array to see if the certain tag someone searched in is in the array(because I can't explode it whilst using SELECT).

Can anyone help or is it impossible?

Thank you all for your help, it worked.

Comment: Don't forget to accept whatever answer has helped.

Answer (score 3):

There's a `mysql` function called `FIND_IN_SET` which operates on comma separated strings.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET('some_tag', post_tags)>0
```

Documentation here: [Mysql FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to normalize data and move tags to a separate table and then join tags to your entity. Search would be fast and easy =)

Answer (score 0):

Read $tags_str from your data base.

Convert string to array:

```
   <?php
    $tags_str = "value1, value2, value3";
    $tags_arr = explode(', ', $tags_str);
    ?>
```

Then use [in_array()](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) PHP function for searching mathes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "LIKE" in your select query

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE tag LIKE '%search_value%'
```

Comment: This would fail if you had for example tags: 'cat food','cat food suplies'.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your database with

```
tags {
  object_id
  tag_id
}
```

Or, if you're lazy, just do

```
UPDATE tags = CONCAT(",", tags, ",") FROM table
```

And then

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%,selected_tag,%'
```